# Background image shows when referenced in HTML but not when referenced in CSS

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

My css file is in the same directory as my html file, and the background image file exists in the images directory. It shows up if I put it directly into the body tag, but not if I reference it in the css file. Directory structure is root - images, html & css are in root, picture is in images.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title> title </title>
<meta name="Author" content="me">
<meta name="Description" content="Description.">
<meta name="Keywords" content="blah blah">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display|Lobster+Two:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>
```

...and, of course, the rest of the file, finishing with `</body></html>`.

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: none; 
    margin: auto;
    background: #ccc url("images/mainbg.jpg") repeat-x fixed top left, url("images/body-x2.png") repeat-x fixed bottom left;
}
```

Comment: Does your `<body>` have a height or any content when the image is set in CSS? Also, you may want to just use `background-image` for testing in case you have any syntactical errors

Comment: if your body dosen't contain anything try adding height to the body with css e.g `height: 100px`

Comment: Yes, I have content in the body; I thought of that as a potential issue. Unfortunately, the content did not help with getting the background to display.

Comment: Also, I have tried using background-image, as well as background. Neither was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the background color declaration, #ccc, and make sure that if you have no content in `<body>` that you also declare a height of 100vh or something like that.

[codepen example](http://sl.ookb.co/1G84Dcx)

Comment: I added the color to verify that the line of css was being parsed. It does not, actually, seem to be showing up, either. The padding declaration is definitely working, though, because it changed when I refreshed after adding it, so it IS *seeing* the body CSS information... just not the background, for some reason.

Comment: I just changed the color to #000 to verify, and it definitely is totally ignoring the entire line of background information.

Comment: @dpenguin What you have will not work: background: #ccc url("images/mainbg.jpg") repeat-x fixed top left, url("images/body-x2.png") repeat-x fixed bottom left; — no background color can be decared

This will work: background: url("images/mainbg.jpg") repeat-x fixed top left, url("images/body-x2.png") repeat-x fixed bottom left;

No color declaration, only image declarations.

And you have to have a height declaration for the body. Check out the codepen example I linked too

Comment: You're welcome. Those long combo properties are hard to get right, especially now that you can add more than one image! if you want to add a background color, I think you can do it by adding an additional background-color: #ccc; property.

Comment: Thanks! :) I don't really need the color; I was just trying to see if it was being used. :)